# If I can serialize a method object (include its logical info) and transfer it to remote server in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, serialization

Here is a scenario that I want to transfer an object which may implement a specify interface like ITask to remote service in specify format(bytes array? json? or xml?). And when service receives and deserialize the object, it runs the specify method.

Following is the sample code of above scenario:

ITask:

```
interface ITask { void run();}
```

Client logical code:

```
void sendObj(ITask task){ 
    var content = SerializeObjectWithMethods(task);
    httpClient.send(remoteServer, content);
}
```

Service logical code:

```
void receiveObj(){
    var handler = listener.Accept();
    var data = handler.Receive();
    ITask task = DeserializeObjWithMethods(data);
    task.run();
}
```

So, does C# can implement the above scenario?

ps. 
when I read spark document, I saw it can send task to other clusters (seems by using java.rmi.*) which is really an interesting thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't serialize an object over, you serialize the state of an object. If you mean send over an object that the remote side knows absolutely nothing about, except for a known interface, then I guess just send a compiled assembly over and the remote server can use reflection to pull the ITask interface out and run it.